# Regex for multiple email addresses in one line

Tags: regex, email-validation

I currently have this regex:

```
/\w+@\w+\.\w+/
```

It works great for a string like this one:

```
foo@bar.com, bar@foo.com, far@boo.com
```

However, it doesn't work for emails with two periods before or after the "@", for example:

```
foo.bar@bar.edu.fr
```

How can I modify the regex for it to work with the second string as well?

Thanks! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a character class instead of `\w` and add `.` into it. Something like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK6rY6/3)

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising given you've hardcoded one period in your regex. Use `\S+` to match any non-whitespace character:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\S+@\S+", "foo.bar@bar.edu.fr")
['foo.bar@bar.edu.fr']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for the second string but doesn't work with the first string (foo@bar.com, bar@foo.com, far@boo.com)